# Arithmetic and changing pattern

Tags: php, loops, math

I have a loop printing out items in a row. Each row contains 4 items.

So every even one (0 and 2) have a specific background image. The uneven ones (1 and 3) have a different one.

Now for the next row I need to change the pattern so 0 and 2 print out the background image that was previously used for 1 and 3.

I thought about doing if `($i = 0 || 2 || 5 || 7 ...)` { but the plan is there will be possibly 100's of items eventually.

**Current Code:**

```
$i = 0;
while ($query->have_posts()) { 
    $query->the_post();
    if ($i % 2 == 0) { 
        // print out dark image
    } else {
        // print out light image
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Do you mind clarifying your question? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: 1st row (contains 4): dark, light, dark, light.... 2nd row (contains 4): light, dark, light, dark... 3rd row (contains 4): dark, light, dark, light... and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your pattern repeats every **8** iterations

Try this

```
if ($i % 8 < 4) { // 0 1 2 3
  if ($i % 2 == 0) {
    // dark
  }
  else {
    // light
  }
}
else { // 4 5 6 7
  if ($i % 2 == 0) {
    // light
  }
  else {
    // dark
  }
}
```

Comment: Cheers for that. Works well!